# Is my opinion right or wrong ? ( hardware acceleration )

Tags: drivers, video, vlc

I always thought/think that hardware acceleration is bad because if you for normal/smooth playback of video must in player turn on the hardware acceleration it means that your CPU is weak. So if I in Vlc or any any other player must use hardware acceleration(on Ubuntu VDPAU for Nvidia) that means to me tha my CPU is to weak.So is my opinion right or wrong? the same goes if I in any player must change some other setting for normal playback. Am I wrong? do i need change my opinion?

Answer (score 0):

*Hardware acceleration* is the use of computer hardware to perform some functions faster than is possible in software running on a more general-purpose CPU. Examples of hardware acceleration include blitting acceleration functionality in graphics processing units (GPUs).

The main difference between hardware and software is concurrency, allowing hardware to be much faster than software. Hardware accelerators are designed for computationally intensive software code. Depending upon granularity, hardware acceleration can vary from a small functional unit to a large functional block (like motion estimation in MPEG-2).

[Source Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_acceleration)

Comment: I was wrong. Tnx for helping me

Comment: You're welcome, if it solves your question in any way don't forget to mark it as solved.